# Разночтение в начертании кавычек

Tags: пунктуация

Почему вышло, что кавычки имеют две формы начертания и почему кавычки в виде двойных апострофов не употребляются в печати?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типов кавычек больше, т.н. елочки и лапочки - просто наиболее употребительны в отечественной полиграфической практике. 
Если очень кратко, то елочки идут из французского, лапочки - из английского и немецкого, где они употребляются наряду с перевернутыми елочками. В английском также употребляются одиночные кавычки, едва ли не чаще всех остальных типов.

В том, что сохраняются два типа кавычек есть определенный смысл, при вложенности кавычек (например, при оформлении прямой речи) используются кавычки разных типов. Впрочем, при компьютерной верстке правилами использования кавычек стали пренебрегать и на практике можно встретить кавычки самого разного вида.

Comment: > вложенности кавычек 

Насколько я помню, случаи вложенности кавычек в русском минимизируются. Так, если встречаются две закрывающие пары кавычек реально пишется только одна. См. рекомендацию из [википедии][1]:

Если по техническим причинам невозможен набор кавычек другого рисунка, кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются[3][4].

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Вы, возможно, не поняли смысла фразы. Она означает, что, если технически невозможно употребление кавычек разного рисунка, используется рисунок одного типа и кавычки не повторяются. Рекомендация сама по себе спорна, да и технически сейчас трудно себе представить такую ситуацию. Что такое "минимзируются случаи вложенности" я даже не могу представить, ибо без проблем могу написать фразу с тремя-четырьмя вложенными уровнями кавычек.


В прошлом обсуждении я написал пример: «Он сказал - "Я уже прочитал книгу «Командир счастливой "Щуки"»"».

Что прикажете тут "минимизировать"?!

Answer (score 2):

"Елочки" (они же "шевроны") - это « и ». Происходят из "немецкой" типографики, откуда перешли и в русскую. "Лапки"  здесь, к сожалению, корректно не отражаются, в русской традиции выглядят как запятые: открывающие - внизу строки, глядящие "наружу", закрывающие - вверху, также наружу и "перевернутые" (надеюсь, понятно описала).

После появления ПК долгое время культура употребления кавычек была нарушена, в особенности "лапок", когда хождение приобрела "английская" манера их написания - обе пары вверху и глядящие внутрь (по последнему могу ошибаться - давно уже такого не видела).

При наличии "вложенных" кавычек, как уже было приведено в примере Бегемотуса, первыми идут "шевроны", внутри них - "лапки". В случае, если подряд идут закрывающие кавычки двух типов (должно быть "»), то ставят обычно только одну пару (это примерно как многоточие в цитате поглощает запятую).